# Force merging in a branch in git

Tags: git, git-merge

Currently I am on branch `foo`, and I want to merge changes from branch `bar`, which git apparently thinks is part of `foo`'s history, due to reasons that are complicated to explain.

Unfortunately, the consequence is that if I run

```
git checkout foo
git merge bar
```

I will get the messages `Already up-to-date` although there are changes in branch `bar` that I want to get into branch `foo`.

I have considered two possible solutions.

One possibility is to simply checkout `bar`, copy it somewhere else, checkout `foo`, and then manually perform the merge. This will work but I would prefer a less manual solution if such exists.

Another possibility is to do the reverse merge, that is, merge `foo` into `bar` instead.
Unfortunately, when I tried this, git's automerge erases exactly those changes in `bar` that I want to preserve and replace them with changes from `foo`, which is undesirable.

How can I force git to pretend `bar` is in the future and `foo` is in the past, to allow a merge of `bar` into `foo`?

Comment: Are both foo and bar remote branches or local?

Comment: @AzizShaikh, both local.

Comment: Could you draw some ASCII art of the branches to explain, why Git's claim (`already up-to-date`) is wrong?

Comment: You can assume that `bar` is a direct ancester of `foo`, but I want git to treat it the other way around during the merge.

Answer (score 1):

Not a clever resolution but should work:

First, run

```
git diff -p foo bar <files_you_want_to_merge> > patch
```

to generate a path file and edit it if necessary (like delete those newer in `foo` than `bar`).

Then run

```
git checkout foo
git apply patch
```

will 'pseudo-merge' `bar` to `foo`.